How do I change the color of the Editor Actions border line?
I have changed almost all colors on vs code manually using the settings.json file

"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Night Owl]": {


I wanted to use the night owl colors for the text but I did not like the borders and background colors so I did a lot of editing but I can not, for the life of me, find what this border is called.
I searched through everything here https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color but it does not change...
this is the only thing left I need to change...


That area is the editorGroupHeader.  I don't see a line there either but you might try     "editorGroupHeader.tabsBackground": "#f000", to set that area to transparent (or another editorGroupHeader.... or editorGroup.... setting.

@Mark I tried all the "editorGroupHeader" but still nothing. most people don't see this line too

It must be something this particular theme implemented.  I tried a bunch of the editorGroup... options like Mark mentioned before answering and I couldn't find anything for it.

The answer bellow solved this... this is really something from the theme...the fix would be just to hide the Editor Actions or send it to the tittle bar.

This "area" of the UI is called the "Editor Actions", but like you, I was completely unable to find a specific color setting for it.  I'm not sure if this theme changes it somehow, because the Default Dark + theme doesn't show a line there.
Nevertheless, maybe a solution is to change the position of the Editor Actions for you.  If you right click anywhere in the tab bar, and hover over "Editor Actions Position", you can move it to the title bar, or hide it.

In the title bar, there is no line anymore, but obviously it moves the icons to a different spot where it may take a bit to get use to:


They forgot to add an option to change this. but this workaround is everything that I need! I set it so the actions are in the title bar. Thank you

You might be looking for contrastBorder (if this is a high-contrast theme).

No, it's just night owl... Not a high-contrast theme I think.

@MrJxtr well, you can try everything with "border" in https://github.com/sdras/night-owl-vscode-theme/blob/main/themes/Night%20Owl-color-theme.json

Already did... Nothing works
